# Identifying and Reverse engineering CRC from Hex

Tags: hex, reverse-engineering, crc

I'm working on identifying and reversing the CRC for a Hex code that I have. 
The hex code contains certain information that I have identified already, but I can't seem to be able to find the CRC and therefore reverse it so I can make changes to the file which is important for me. 
I have a few files of the same type with minor to major changes between them and have been trying to use that to find where the CRC might be located.
I got it down to a few possible locations, however when I put the remainder in a calculator to get the CRC to verify it doesn't work.

I have a hunch that CRC-CCITT was used, but no calculator and no variation of the code seems to identify that.

Is there any other way to identify and reverse the CRC?

I thought about writing code for this, but I'm not sure that will help since I'm not absolutely sure which CRC is being used.

I created an XOR file that shows me the differences. It helped me verify that I'm looking for a 16-bit CRC, but not exactly what the Polynomial might be, also it might be in 2 different places.

Now I'm having trouble identifying that start-to-end addresses from which the CRC is calculated. The Hex code I have is 18H lines*16 bytes, 25D lines*16 bytes, each line so it's very time consuming to try every variation in a calculator hoping I find the CRC. Is there any way to identify the start-to-end addresses?

Here is the XOR file for reference:

```
00000000000001710000000000000005
00100d0032b100000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000007fc90000
00000000000000000000000000000000
0171000000000000000500100d000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000a00
0c400000003900000000000000090000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000001a00000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000
```

The locations that are possible for the CRC could be:

```
02C and 02D = 7FC9

014 and 015 = 32B1
```

Comment: @rcgldr Thank you, can I use the COR data to brute force the CRC?
I now have the XOR file and it came down to the same 2 locations I had already suspected they were at. The other changes I recognize as code with other meaning. It did confirm my suspicion that it could be 16-bit CRC, still don't have the exact polynomial though.

Comment: @rcgldr thank you! I added the example of the XOR file.

Comment: @rcgldr Oh yes, I didn't realise the line counter counts in hex! I will update the example data.

Comment: The reason I think it's CRC is that I know that a similar data used CRC to error proof. What other methods might be used to make sure the file hasn't been corrupted aside from regular checksum?

Comment: I haven't found anything yet with the second XOR example. It is possible to put a CRC in the middle of data, but it's awkward. I didn't find a CRC match at 0x2C and 0x2D in either case. I didn't try 014 and 015 yet. I found some at 0x4B, 0x4C for the first one, but not the second one.